# Modify login view in django crispy form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I am doing authentication using crispy forms in Django. I would like to modify labels `username` and `password` in login view, but I can't find any solution to do it (I think that I have to create my own login form, but maybe it is possible to extend it).

***urls.py***

```
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

***login.html***

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
                Login
                {{ form|crispy}}
            </legend>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">Don't have an account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a> </small>

    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Can i have full source code

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what you're trying to achieve but if you're trying to modify the look of the fields you can do this in your forms.py file the fields you want to modify you can add bootstrap classes their for example in my login form I did this:

```
 email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', max_length=50, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class":"form-control  mb-3",'placeholder': 'Email'}))
 password = forms.CharField(label='Password',widget= forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class":"form-control mb-3",'placeholder': 'Password'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Django way would be to create a `forms.py` like described in Haris Ahmad's answer but Johnson's answer is valid as well.

You can decorate your input elements with the `<label>` element like so:

```html
<label for="id_login">Username or email</label>
<input id="id_login" name="login" type="email" class="form-control">

<label for="id_password">Password</label>
<input id="id_password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control">
```

The values provided to the label will be shown in the input elements.

---

Full example:

```html
<div class="content-section">
  <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">

        <!-- Username field -->
        <label for="id_login">Username or email</label>
        <input id="id_login" name="login" type="email" class="form-control">

        <!-- Password field -->
        <label for="id_password">Password</label>
        <input id="id_password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control">

      </legend>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info">Login</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="border-top pt-3">
    <small class="text-muted">Don't have an account? 
      <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a> 
    </small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30142262)

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand your question but if you want more control over your input fields you should render raw html instead of form. You just have to ensure the field name of the input matched the name of the form field

```
<input name="username" type="text" .......>
```

Comment: you can inspect the form in your browser to check the form name

Comment: It works differently in crispy forms, are you familiar with them or just make assumptions on your HTML stack?

Comment: I am familiar with them